# Database configuration while installing Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, sqlite

I have a problem while installing drupal 7, despite the sqlite version being 3.7.5, and I have MySql database installed 
[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's up with that sqlite error, but if you want to use MySQL, you need the enable PDO Mysql extension (pdo_mysql.dll/so) in your php.ini

Comment: Do you see the mysql option now? If not, have you restarted apache?

Comment: i've restated apache ,but nothing !!